# How can I format or trim a number to remove prefixed '0' ?

Tags: javascript

I have two numbers: `02.95` and `03.28`

I would like to remove the extra 0 from front.

My Expected output: `2.95` and `3.28`

How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: `str.replace(/^0+/, '')`

Comment: You don't have two numbers. You have two strings.

Comment: `parseFloat('02.95')`;

Comment: the thing to point out is that you actual have two strings and want to make numbers from them...regardless of how many zeros you have up front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are individual strings themselves, the fastest and shortest way would be to convert them to numeric values with the [Unary Plus (`+`) prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()):

```
+"02.95"  ->  2.95
+"03.28"  ->  3.28
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked :)